# Are these two lines the same, '? ... :' vs '??'?

Tags: c#

Is there a difference between these two lines?

```
MyName = (s.MyName == null) ? string.Empty : s.MyName
```

or

```
MyName = s.MyName ?? string.Empty
```

Comment: Check IL of them, that way you will have a better idea if they will produce the same code or they are being handled differently

Comment: @manman If someone doesn't understand the high level code what gives you the impression that the IL code will be *more* readable?

Comment: @Servy When some is that curious about learning the difference and everybody else is covering the high level discussions, it's a good idea to point out other ways to understand the difference and if he's very curious, he can go and just compare the result, no need to read the whole IL

Comment: The only difference is whether you evaluate `s.MyName` once or twice.

Comment: @Servy because you don't have to understand the IL code, you just have to `diff` it

Comment: My God! Where is Mr. [Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) ?

Comment: It really is a battle of the ego's on SO isn't it? You're not contributing anything unless you answer the question with an explanation.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

UPDATE: I wrote a blog post that discusses this topic in more depth.  http://www.codeducky.org/properties-fields-and-methods-oh-my/

---

Generally they will return the same result.  However, there are a few cases where you will experience noticeable differences when `MyName` is a property because the `MyName` getter will be executed twice in the first example and only once in the second example.

For example, you may experience performance differences from executing `MyName` twice:

```
string MyName
{
    get 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        return "HELLO";
    }
}
```

Or you may get different results from executing `MyName` twice if `MyName` is stateful:

```
private bool _MyNameHasBeenRead = false;

string MyName
{
    get 
    {
        if(_MyNameHasBeenRead)
                throw new Exception("Can't read MyName twice");
        _MyNameHasBeenRead = true;
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        return "HELLO";
    }
}
```

Or you may get different results from executing `MyName` twice if `MyName` can be changed on a different thread:

```
void ChangeMyNameAsync()
{
    //MyName set to null in another thread which makes it 
    //possible for the first example to return null
    Task.Run(() => this.MyName = null);
}

string MyName { get; set; }
```

Here's how the actual code is compiled. First the piece with the ternary expression:

```
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // s
IL_0008:  callvirt    s.get_MyName       <-- first call
IL_000D:  brfalse.s   IL_0017
IL_000F:  ldloc.0     // s
IL_0010:  callvirt    s.get_MyName       <-- second call
IL_0015:  br.s        IL_001C
IL_0017:  ldsfld      System.String.Empty
IL_001C:  call        set_MyName
```

and here is the piece with the null-coalescing operator:

```
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // s
IL_0008:  callvirt    s.get_MyName       <-- only call
IL_000D:  dup         
IL_000E:  brtrue.s    IL_0016
IL_0010:  pop         
IL_0011:  ldsfld      System.String.Empty
IL_0016:  call        s.set_MyName
```

As you can see the compiled code for the ternary operator will make two calls to get the property value, whereas the null-coalescing operator will only do 1.

Comment: @SabdielRivera That wasn't the part of the question. The difference is clearly shown here.

Comment: `MyName = s.MyName ?? string.Empty` won't execute the getter twice if `MyName` is a property.  So if you don't want to execute the getter twice, then you should use the second line.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding IL examples of the two pieces of code. For a full [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) example, look at https://www.dropbox.com/s/x6zqdsjlkosxchf/SO21052437.linq

Comment: I think you missed an "s" on the last part of the IL code; currently it reads `et_MyName`, which should be `set_MyName`.

Comment: Also, the long version with `?:` might actually result in `null` for the above reasons. It might be more illustrative if `"Value from other thread"` above was actually a `null` string. Then that would show that the result **could** be null. Same could happen with the stateful object if the object decided to return a string instance on the first invocation of the `get` accessoor and return null on the second invocation only.

Comment: Also note that the C# 4.0 language specs ensure (in §7.14) that MyValue gets indeed evaluated twice thus preventing the jitter to optimize out that double call (as I thought it would at first)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I edited my third example to use null rather than "Value from other thread"

Answer (score 26):

If the property is more than a simple getter, you might be executing a function twice in the non-null case for the first one.

If the property is in a stateful object, then the second call to the property might return a different result:

```
class MyClass
{
    private IEnumerator<string> _next = Next();

    public MyClass()
    {
        this._next.MoveNext();
    }

    public string MyName
    {
        get
        {
            var n = this._next.Current;
            this._next.MoveNext();
            return n;
        }
    }


    public static IEnumerator<string> Next()
    {
        yield return "foo";
        yield return "bar";
    }
}
```

Also, in the non-string case, the class might overload == to do something different than the ternary operator. I don't believe that the ternary operator can be overloaded.

Comment: Ternary operator definitely cannot be overloaded.  Even C++, which lets you overload practically every other operator, has no way of overloading `?:`.  I've not seen any language which does.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman There's always Scala, where you can roll your own ;)

Answer (score 9):

The only difference is whether you evaluate `s.MyName` twice or once. The first will do it twice in the case that `s.MyName` is not null, the second will only ever evaluate it once.

In most cases, this difference doesn't matter, and I'd go with the second because it's more clear and concise.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, both are the same, and it is the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

> It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

If we talk about efficiency then

```
string MyName = (s.MyName == null) ? string.Empty : s.MyName;
string MyName2 = s.MyName ?? string.Empty;
```

If I use a dissembler then I can see that *the first statement needs 19 statements* to be executed by the compiler whereas *the second statement required only 12 statements* to be executed.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the name. I wanted to see if Java also has this ?? operator. And it doesn't, so I'll stick with the ternary operator for both.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do the same. `??` is shorthand for checking for null.

Answer (score 0):

They accomplish the same task.

Only difference would be readability as to whether your coworkers or whomever is reading the code understands the syntax.

EDIT: Additionally the first option can evaluate the property `MyName` twice.

Answer (score -1):

No. Both are doing the same thing. Second one is efficient.
Which returns the actual value if it is not null. Else the right-hand side value will be returned.

Refer this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Hope this helps.