# Extract all links from web page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, hyperlink

I need to extract all links from a web page. My current solution only extracts links from `<a>` tags:

```
def get_links(url)
  Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read).css("a").map do |link|
    if (href = link.attr("href")) && href.match(/^https?:/)
      href
    end
  end.compact
end
```

this solution is copypasted from one of the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700367/getting-all-links-of-a-webpage-using-ruby)

Problem is links in html documents don't necessarily appear as `href` attribute inside `<a>` tag. I need to extract all full/relative http/https links from html/css files. Is there a solid 'settled' for this?

Comment: Give the html source also and some of the outputs which you want(just to give us a hint)

Comment: literally any web page. maybe I'm asking too much, but I need a good starter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using Ruby's built-in URI class. Look at the [`extract`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-extract) method.

It's not as smart as what you could write using Nokogiri and looking in anchors, images, scripts, `on_click` handlers, etc., but it's a good and fast starting point.

For instance, looking at the content of this question's page:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'uri'

URI.extract(open('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069348/extract-all-links-from-web-page/21069456#21069456').read).grep(/^https?:/)
# => ["http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=fde65a5a78c6",
#     "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069348/extract-all-links-from-web-page",
#     "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069348/extract-all-links-from-web-page",
#     "https://stackauth.com",
#     "http://chat.stackoverflow.com",
#     "http://blog.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://schema.org/Article",
#     "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700367/getting-all-links-of-a-webpage-using-ruby",
#     "https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgtEd.jpg?s=32&g=1",
#     "http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-extract",
#     "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/71770d043c0f7e3c7bc5f74190015c26?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG",
#     "http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy'",
#     "http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service'",
#     "http://superuser.com/questions/698312/if-32-bit-machines-can-only-handle-numbers-up-to-232-why-can-i-write-100000000",
#     "http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47868/why-did-smeagol-become-addicted-to-the-ring-when-bilbo-did-not",
#     "http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145672/idiom-for-trying-and-failing-falling-short-and-being-disapproved",
#     "http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634191/are-the-integers-closed-under-addition-really",
#     "http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18254/how-to-write-a-c-program-for-multiplication-without-using-and-operator",
#     "http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153563/how-to-align-terms-in-alignat-environment",
#     "http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31426/how-do-have-interesting-events-happen-after-a-success",
#     "http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630339/pedagogy-how-to-cure-students-of-the-law-of-universal-linearity",
#     "http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17005/produce-the-number-2014-without-any-numbers-in-your-source-code",
#     "http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15595/why-are-so-many-badly-written-papers-still-published",
#     "http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153598/how-to-draw-empty-nodes-in-tikz-qtree",
#     "http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145157/a-formal-way-to-say-i-dont-want-to-sound-too-cocky",
#     "http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93256/is-it-possible-to-split-baryons-and-extract-useable-energy-out-of-it",
#     "http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40213/counting-false-values-at-the-ends-of-a-list",
#     "http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96139/difference-between-a-bus-and-a-wire",
#     "http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/921/why-do-some-aircraft-have-multiple-ailerons-per-wing",
#     "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052437/are-these-two-lines-the-same-vs",
#     "http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/14414/if-there-are-no-human-races-why-do-human-populations-have-several-distinct-phen",
#     "http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems",
#     "http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/largest-number-printable",
#     "http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108858/seek-argument-in-command-dd",
#     "http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6375/can-the-chinese-script-be-used-to-record-non-chinese-languages",
#     "http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31346/techniques-for-making-undead-scary-again",
#     "http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632705/why-are-mathematical-proofs-that-rely-on-computers-controversial",
#     "http://blog.stackexchange.com?blb=1",
#     "http://chat.stackoverflow.com",
#     "http://data.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://stackexchange.com/legal",
#     "http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy",
#     "http://stackexchange.com/about/hiring",
#     "http://engine.adzerk.net/r?e=eyJhdiI6NDE0LCJhdCI6MjAsImNtIjo5NTQsImNoIjoxMTc4LCJjciI6Mjc3NiwiZG0iOjQsImZjIjoyODYyLCJmbCI6Mjc1MSwibnciOjIyLCJydiI6MCwicHIiOjExNSwic3QiOjAsInVyIjoiaHR0cDovL3N0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29tL2Fib3V0L2NvbnRhY3QiLCJyZSI6MX0&s=hRods5B22XvRBwWIwtIMekcyNF8",
#     "http://meta.stackoverflow.com",
#     "http://stackoverflow.com",
#     "http://serverfault.com",
#     "http://superuser.com",
#     "http://webapps.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://askubuntu.com",
#     "http://webmasters.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://gamedev.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://tex.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://programmers.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://unix.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://apple.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://wordpress.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://gis.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://electronics.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://android.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://security.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://dba.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://drupal.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://ux.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://mathematica.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology",
#     "http://photo.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://scifi.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://cooking.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://diy.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://stackexchange.com/sites#lifearts",
#     "http://english.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://skeptics.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://judaism.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://travel.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://christianity.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://gaming.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://bicycles.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://rpg.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation",
#     "http://math.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://stats.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://cstheory.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://physics.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://mathoverflow.net",
#     "http://stackexchange.com/sites#science",
#     "http://stackapps.com",
#     "http://meta.stackoverflow.com",
#     "http://area51.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://careers.stackoverflow.com",
#     "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/",
#     "http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/",
#     "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/",
#     "http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.gif",
#     "https:",
#     "https:'==document.location.protocol,",
#     "https://ssl",
#     "http://www",
#     "https://secure",
#     "http://edge",
#     "https:",
#     "https://sb",
#     "http://b"]
```

There are a lot of other entries, but using `grep` filters them out using a simple `/^https?:/` pattern.

A simple starting point with Nokogiri is:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069348/extract-all-links-from-web-page/21069456#21069456').read)
urls = doc.search('a, img').map{ |tag| 
  case tag.name.downcase
  when 'a'
    tag['href']
  when 'img'
    tag['src']
  end
}

urls 
# => ["//stackexchange.com/sites",
#     "http://chat.stackoverflow.com",
#     "http://blog.stackexchange.com",
#     "//stackoverflow.com",
#     "//meta.stackoverflow.com",
#     "//careers.stackoverflow.com",
#     "//stackexchange.com",
#     "/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2f21069348%2fextract-all-links-from-web-page%2f21069456",
#     "/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2f21069348%2fextract-all-links-from-web-page%2f21069456",
#     "/tour",
#     "/help",
#     "//careers.stackoverflow.com",
#     "/",
#     "/questions",
#     "/tags",
#     "/about",
#     "/users",
#     "/questions/ask",
#     "/about",
#     nil,
#     "/questions/21069348/extract-all-links-from-web-page",
#     nil,
#     nil,
#     "#",
#     "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700367/getting-all-links-of-a-webpage-using-ruby",
#     "/questions/tagged/html",
#     "/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails",
#     "/questions/tagged/ruby",
#     "/questions/tagged/regex",
#     "/questions/tagged/hyperlink",
#     "/q/21069348",
#     "/posts/21069348/edit",
#     "/users/2886945/ivan-denisov",
#     "/users/2886945/ivan-denisov",
#     "/users/2767755/arup-rakshit",
#     "/users/2886945/ivan-denisov",
#     nil,
#     nil,
#     "/questions/21069348/extract-all-links-from-web-page?answertab=active#tab-top",
#     "/questions/21069348/extract-all-links-from-web-page?answertab=oldest#tab-top",
#     "/questions/21069348/extract-all-links-from-web-page?answertab=votes#tab-top",
#     nil,
#     nil,
#     nil,
#     "http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-extract",
#     "/a/21069456",
#     "/posts/21069456/revisions",
#     "/users/128421/the-tin-man",
#     "/users/128421/the-tin-man",
#     nil,
#     nil,
#     nil,
#     nil,
#     "http://regex101.com/r/hN4dI0",
#     "/a/21069536",
#     "/users/1214800/r3mus",
#     "/users/1214800/r3mus",
#     nil,
#     nil,
#     "/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2f21069348%2fextract-all-links-from-web-page%23new-answer",
#     "#",
#     "http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy",
#     "http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service",
#     "/questions/tagged/html",
#     "/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails",
#     "/questions/tagged/ruby",
#     "/questions/tagged/regex",
#     "/questions/tagged/hyperlink",
#     "/questions/ask",
#     "/questions/tagged/html",
#     "/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails",
#     "/questions/tagged/ruby",
#     "/questions/tagged/regex",
#     "/questions/tagged/hyperlink",
#     "?lastactivity",
#     "/q/21052437",
#     "/questions/21052437/are-these-two-lines-the-same-vs",
#     "/q/6700367",
#     "/questions/6700367/getting-all-links-of-a-webpage-using-ruby",
#     "/q/430966",
#     "/questions/430966/regex-for-links-in-html-text",
#     "/q/3703712",
#     "/questions/3703712/extract-all-links-from-a-html-page-exclude-links-from-a-specific-table",
#     "/q/5120171",
#     "/questions/5120171/extract-links-from-a-web-page",
#     "/q/6816138",
#     "/questions/6816138/extract-absolute-links-from-a-page-uisng-htmlparser",
#     "/q/10177910",
#     "/questions/10177910/php-regular-expression-extracting-html-links",
#     "/q/10217857",
#     "/questions/10217857/extracting-background-images-from-a-web-page-parsing-htmlcss",
#     "/q/11300496",
#     "/questions/11300496/how-to-extract-a-link-from-head-tag-of-a-remote-page-using-curl",
#     "/q/11307491",
#     "/questions/11307491/how-to-extract-all-links-on-a-page-using-crawler4j",
#     "/q/17712493",
#     "/questions/17712493/extract-links-from-bbcode-with-ruby",
#     "/q/20290869",
#     "/questions/20290869/strip-away-html-tags-from-extracted-links",
#     "//stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot",
#     "http://superuser.com/questions/698312/if-32-bit-machines-can-only-handle-numbers-up-to-232-why-can-i-write-100000000",
#     "http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47868/why-did-smeagol-become-addicted-to-the-ring-when-bilbo-did-not",
#     "http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145672/idiom-for-trying-and-failing-falling-short-and-being-disapproved",
#     "http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634191/are-the-integers-closed-under-addition-really",
#     "http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18254/how-to-write-a-c-program-for-multiplication-without-using-and-operator",
#     "http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153563/how-to-align-terms-in-alignat-environment",
#     "http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31426/how-do-have-interesting-events-happen-after-a-success",
#     "http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630339/pedagogy-how-to-cure-students-of-the-law-of-universal-linearity",
#     "http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17005/produce-the-number-2014-without-any-numbers-in-your-source-code",
#     "http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15595/why-are-so-many-badly-written-papers-still-published",
#     "http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153598/how-to-draw-empty-nodes-in-tikz-qtree",
#     "http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145157/a-formal-way-to-say-i-dont-want-to-sound-too-cocky",
#     "http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93256/is-it-possible-to-split-baryons-and-extract-useable-energy-out-of-it",
#     "http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40213/counting-false-values-at-the-ends-of-a-list",
#     "http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96139/difference-between-a-bus-and-a-wire",
#     "http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/921/why-do-some-aircraft-have-multiple-ailerons-per-wing",
#     "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052437/are-these-two-lines-the-same-vs",
#     "http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/14414/if-there-are-no-human-races-why-do-human-populations-have-several-distinct-phen",
#     "http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems",
#     "http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/largest-number-printable",
#     "http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108858/seek-argument-in-command-dd",
#     "http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6375/can-the-chinese-script-be-used-to-record-non-chinese-languages",
#     "http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31346/techniques-for-making-undead-scary-again",
#     "http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632705/why-are-mathematical-proofs-that-rely-on-computers-controversial",
#     "#",
#     "/feeds/question/21069348",
#     "/about",
#     "/help",
#     "/help/badges",
#     "http://blog.stackexchange.com?blb=1",
#     "http://chat.stackoverflow.com",
#     "http://data.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://stackexchange.com/legal",
#     "http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy",
#     "http://stackexchange.com/about/hiring",
#     "http://engine.adzerk.net/r?e=eyJhdiI6NDE0LCJhdCI6MjAsImNtIjo5NTQsImNoIjoxMTc4LCJjciI6Mjc3NiwiZG0iOjQsImZjIjoyODYyLCJmbCI6Mjc1MSwibnciOjIyLCJydiI6MCwicHIiOjExNSwic3QiOjAsInVyIjoiaHR0cDovL3N0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29tL2Fib3V0L2NvbnRhY3QiLCJyZSI6MX0&s=hRods5B22XvRBwWIwtIMekcyNF8",
#     nil,
#     "/contact",
#     "http://meta.stackoverflow.com",
#     "http://stackoverflow.com",
#     "http://serverfault.com",
#     "http://superuser.com",
#     "http://webapps.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://askubuntu.com",
#     "http://webmasters.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://gamedev.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://tex.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://programmers.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://unix.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://apple.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://wordpress.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://gis.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://electronics.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://android.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://security.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://dba.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://drupal.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://ux.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://mathematica.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology",
#     "http://photo.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://scifi.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://cooking.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://diy.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://stackexchange.com/sites#lifearts",
#     "http://english.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://skeptics.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://judaism.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://travel.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://christianity.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://gaming.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://bicycles.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://rpg.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation",
#     "http://math.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://stats.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://cstheory.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://physics.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://mathoverflow.net",
#     "http://stackexchange.com/sites#science",
#     "http://stackapps.com",
#     "http://meta.stackoverflow.com",
#     "http://area51.stackexchange.com",
#     "http://careers.stackoverflow.com",
#     "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/",
#     "http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/",
#     "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/",
#     "https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgtEd.jpg?s=32&g=1",
#     "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/71770d043c0f7e3c7bc5f74190015c26?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG",
#     "https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmgha.jpg?s=32&g=1",
#     "/posts/21069348/ivc/8228",
#     "http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.gif"]
```

That uses a `case` statement to apply a bit of "smarts" to know which field should be retrieved from a particular type of tag. More work would need to be done, since an anchor could use an `on_click`, and there could be other tags being used for JavaScript events.

Comment: Yep. Nokogiri is more flexible after all. I will be able to convert relative links to absolute, etc...

Comment: Use URI or Addressable::URI to manipulate URIs. They are designed for it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the Tin Man's answer is unquestionably the best route. If you *do* need a catchall regular expression that will grab all urls (as close to accurate as possible) this should work:

```
\w+:\/\/[\w.-]+(?::?\d{1,5})?[-\w.\/?=&%]*
```

See some examples: http://regex101.com/r/hN4dI0

Note that it requires the protocol prefix (`http://`, `mailto://`), so it won't match just `www.google.com`.

Comment: That's what URI does internally.

Comment: @theTinMan yeah ;) I mostly put this here for people who find the question and aren't using rails.